# Multiple custom fonts with AWS lambda not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ffmpeg, fonts

I'm using AWS lambda with python and ffmpeg to add textual watermark over images. I added a custom font i.e Quicksand to my lambda function like this:

1- Create a fonts directory in the root of the function and add the font file (.ttf) and a font.conf file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

2- Added an environment variable like this

```
FONTCONFIG_PATH = "/var/task/fonts"
```

It was working fine until I chose to add more fonts. Now when I try to use some font other than the Quicksand e.g Arial, it still uses the Quicksand font. I'm not sure why? In the CloudWatch Logs I can see it is still trying to access the Quicksand font rather than the Arial one even when the code is right. Any caching issue or something else?

My folder structure:
[image]

Cloudwatch logs:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x70b5bc0] Using "/var/task/fonts/Quicksand.ttf"
```

Maybe its a caching issue? I'm not sure.

My ffmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=font=‘Quicksand.ttf'
:text='StackOverflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=w-mod(max(t-0\,0)*(w+tw)/6\,(w+tw)):y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy Newwwtext.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Luiz Correia advice, I ended up using s3 bucket to store the font files. Inside my lambda function I copied the font file from s3 bucket to the `/tmp` directory and then used it inside the ffmpeg command. I also updated the ffmpeg command to use `fontfile` instead of `font` inside drawtext, like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=‘Quicksand.ttf'
:text='StackOverflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=w-mod(max(t-0\,0)*(w+tw)/6\,(w+tw)):y=(h-text_h)/2" -codec:a copy Newwwtext.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

you need be more specific about where your files are.

And how many times your lambda run.
I think the best solution was using the S3 or the EFS.

Comment: Which files are you referring to? My font files? They are part of the lambda binary image / zip. And my lambda runs frequently. How does the lambda execution frequency effects here?

Comment: Sorry for that, but if your lambda are always in hot start, you can download the font from s3 and put it in the /tmp directory.

So, if the fonts are in the binary image. It should work.

Can you provide the ffmpeg code?

The ffmpeg has some tricks, like you need set fontsdir and force_style



```bash
-vf "subtitles=(srt location):fontsdir=(folder location of font):force_style='FontName=Quicksand.ttf,Fontsize=12'"
```


On your example:



```bash
-vf "subtitles=(srt location):fontsdir=/var/task/fonts/:force_style='FontName=Quicksand.ttf,Fontsize=12'"
```

Comment: I'll try your suggestion, thanks. I've also added my ffmpeg code to the question.